# Which ones are better for my gains, 48-hour-based splits or 72-hour-based splits?

Tags: splits

I exercise daily. I can do it this way: pull, push, legs, pull, push, legs, and so on. As a result, my pull muscles, for example, have a 72-hour recovery time. I can also split my leg exercises into pulling (hamstrings) and pushing (quads) too and make it into pull, push, pull, push. That way, my muscles will have 48 hours to recover. Which should I opt for?

Answer (score 6):

**Whichever you prefer. It really doesn't matter.**

A 2019 review<sup>[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsams.2018.09.223)</sup> concluded:

> it appears that under volume-equated conditions, [resistance training] frequency does not seem to have a pronounced effect of gains in muscle mass.

And that's comparing training programs as disparate as training muscle groups once per week vs four times per week. There's no way you're going to be able to see any difference in results between training 3.5 times per week vs 2.3 times per week.

Comment: But what about recovery?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Higher frequency means lower per-session volume, which means less recovery demands.